# Expanding a list contained in a column, so that each element of the list corresponds to its own column and is represented as a binary variable

Tags: binary-data

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
skill_list                 name               profile                 561 904 468 875 737 402 882...
[561, 564, 632, 859]       Aaron Weidele      wordpress developer      0    0   0   0   0   0   0   
[737, 399, 882, 1086, 5...]Abdelrady Tantawy  full stack developer     0    0   0   0   0   0   0   
[904, 468, 783, 1120, 8...]Abhijeet A Mulgund machine learning dev...  0    0   0   0   0   0   0   [468]                      Abhijeet Tiwari    salesforce programmi...  0    0   0   0   0   0   0
[518, 466, 875, 445, 402..]Abhimanyu Veer A...machine learning devel...0    0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The skill_list column contains a list of encoded skills, which correspond to a developer. I would like to expand each list contained within the skill_list column, so that each encoded skill is represented within its own column as a binary variable (1 for on and 0 for off). Expected output would be:

```
skill_list                 name               profile                 561 904 468 875 737 402 882...
[561, 564, 632, 859]       Aaron Weidele      wordpress developer      1    0   0   0   0   0   0   
[737, 399, 882, 1086, 5...]Abdelrady Tantawy  full stack developer     0    0   0   0   1   0   1   
[904, 468, 783, 1120, 8...]Abhijeet A Mulgund machine learning dev...  0    1   1   0   0   0   0   [468]                      Abhijeet Tiwari    salesforce programmi...  0    0   1   0   0   0   0
[518, 466, 875, 445, 402..]Abhimanyu Veer A...machine learning devel...0    0   0   0   0   1   0
```

I've tried:

```
for index, row in df_vector_matrix["skill_list"].items():
    for item in row:
        for col in df_vector_matrix.columns:
            if item == col:
                df_vector_matrix.loc[item, col] = "1"
        else:
            0
```

I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `MultiLabelBinarizer` from sklearn.
Below example might help.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

lb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
lb_res = lb.fit_transform(df_vector_matrix['skill_list'])

# convert result into dataframe
res = pd.DataFrame(lb_res,columns=lb.classes_)

# concatenate data result and original dataframe
df_vector_matrix = pd.concat([df_vector_matrix,res],axis=1)
```

Below is with the example dataframe, where the `col` column have list values.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
>>> d ={'col':[[1,2,3],[2,3,4,5],[2]],'name':['abc','vdf','rt']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
            col name
0     [1, 2, 3]  abc
1  [2, 3, 4, 5]  vdf
2           [2]   rt
>>> lb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
>>> lb_res = lb.fit_transform(df['col'])
>>> res = pd.DataFrame(lb_res,columns=lb.classes_)
>>> pd.concat([df,res],axis=1)
            col name  1  2  3  4  5
0     [1, 2, 3]  abc  1  1  1  0  0
1  [2, 3, 4, 5]  vdf  0  1  1  1  1
2           [2]   rt  0  1  0  0  0
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip Chhaya! That didn't work, and I'm wondering if that functionality is meant to work on non-sequence data. Because this column contains a list of data, many of the methods I've found haven't worked as expected. Have you used this functionality on sequence data?

Comment: I have added the example for which this method works.

Comment: You are amazing!!! You saved me so much time, thank you so much!!!